# Ayuda con Android - Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference

Tags: android, android-layout, edittext, nullpointerexception

Estimados, al presionar el botón que me debería llevar a la Actividad "Registro" con el fin de crear una cuenta, android me aparece el siguiente error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference
at com.example.ksandoval.loginpro.Registro.onCreate(Registro.java:41).
```

He revisado pero no veo el error, todo esta declarado e instanciado correctamente...(creo).
Agradezco de antemano su ayuda.
Adjunto XML + Class.

Activity:

```
public class Registro extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button btRegistro;
    private EditText etUser, etEmail, etPass;
    private ProgressDialog mProgress;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        btRegistro = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_registro);
        etUser = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_userRegistro);
        etEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_correoRegistro);
        etPass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_passwordRegistro);
        //Progreso
        mProgress = new ProgressDialog(this);

        //string
        String name = etUser.getText().toString();
        String email = etEmail.getText().toString();
        String pass = etPass.getText().toString();

        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(name) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(email) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(pass)){
            //Seteo la barra de progreso
            mProgress.setMessage("Registering, please wait...");
            mProgress.show();
            //Creo el registro para FireBase
            mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,pass).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {

                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    mProgress.dismiss(); //quito el Progress dialog
                    if (task.isSuccessful()){
                        String user_id = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                        Toast.makeText(Registro.this, "Authentication Complete : " + user_id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        limpiarCampos();
                    }else{
                        // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                        //Log.w(TAG, "createUserWithEmail:failure", task.getException());
                        Toast.makeText(Registro.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
        }

    }//fin del oncreate


    //Metodos Propios
    public boolean validarCampos(){
        try{
            String user = etUser.getText().toString();
            String correo = etEmail.getText().toString();
            String pass = etPass.getText().toString();
            if (user.isEmpty() || correo.isEmpty() || pass.isEmpty()){
                Toast.makeText(this, "Tiene campos en blanco", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return false;
            }else {
                return true;
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error al capturar los datos " + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void limpiarCampos(){
        etUser.setText("");
        etEmail.setText("");
        etPass.setText("");
    }}
}
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    tools:context="com.example.ksandoval.loginpro.MainActivity">


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lnlayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_logo"
            style="@style/tv_tituloStyle"
            android:layout_margin="50dp"
            android:text="@string/tv_logo" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_userRegistro"
            style="@style/et_style"
            android:hint="@string/hint_userRegistro"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_correoRegistro"
            style="@style/et_style"
            android:hint="@string/et_correoRegistro"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_passwordRegistro"
            style="@style/et_style"
            android:hint="@string/hint_passRegistro"
            android:inputType="textPassword" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bt_registro"
            style="@style/btn_style"
            android:text="@string/bt_registro" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_kris"
            style="@style/tv_style"
            android:text="@string/tv_kris" />


    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout
```

Comment: [Android Studio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/android-studio/info): Utilizar esta etiqueta solo si la pregunta está asociada al uso, funcionalidades o problemas con el IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Acabo de especificar la actividad a través de un :

```
//Asegura que se esta trabajando sobre una actividad especifica
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_registro);
```

Y ya esta solucionado, muchas gracias de todas formas. Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

En cuanto al error:

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable
>   android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference

Se refiere a que llamas el método `getText()` en una instacia de EditText que tiene un valor null. En realidad estas obteniendo las instancias de los elementos dentro de tu Activity:

```
        btRegistro = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_registro);
        etUser = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_userRegistro);
        etEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_correoRegistro);
        etPass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_passwordRegistro);
```

Pero estos tienen valor null, lo cual se puede deber a 2 causas:

1) El elemento no se encuentra dentro del .xml que cargas por medio de `setContentView()`.

2) No se esta cargando un Layout que contenga los elementos mediante `setContentView()`.

En este caso estas omitiendo la carga de, layout, por esa razón además de tu `EditText`, no se encontrara ninguno de los demás elementos.